# GraphicsMagick with LIBPNG library

Tags: libpng, graphicsmagick

How should ./configure args look like in order to make install to build graphicsmagick with support of JPG conversion?

[image]
This is what I've been doing so far (which not working out):

> ./configure LDFLAGS="-L/Users/my_user/Downloads/libpng-1.6.10" LIBS="-libpng"

Answer (score 0):

You need to install all the external libraries that you want to support before running the configure command.

At the moment, you've got only PNG support. If you want to support JPEGs, you need to install libjpeg. There are different ways to do so depending on your operating system (Mac or Linux?), or you can grab the [sources](http://www.ijg.org/files/) and compile it yourself with the same commands (`./configure`, `make`, `sudo make install`).

Of course, if you want to support JPEG 2000, TIFF, etc you need to install the corresponding libraries too. See README.txt for more info and link on what libraries are needed to read what format.

I don't think you need to pass the `LIBS="-libpng"` to configure, GraphicsMagick should add it by default as long as it's being built with PNG support. You still need the LDFLAGS though as libpng is not "installed" and in a standard path. GraphicsMagick looks into /usr/local/lib by default so if you install the library it should be picked up without you having to do anything.

You can have a look at the text files at the root of GraphicsMagick's archive, there is a `README.TXT` and `INSTALL-unix.txt`, they might prove handy.